# How to install APK on Gabb Z2?

Tags: installation, apk, gabb

I would like to install Spotify on my Gabb Z2 phone. The Gabb phone runs a modified version of Android that is programmed to have only default apps and no store. They somehow managed to get their own app on there, which leads me to believe that there is a way to install apps on this phone.

I try to go to Privacy > Permission Manager > Search > Autofill where the developer options are so I can turn on USB Debugging, it does nothing, the bug was found and patched so that there is no way to access the options. As a side note, I also tried going to About Phone and clicking on the build number 7 times.

I have scoured the internet looking for the solution to my problem, I came close but I was blocked. How to install APK on Gabb Z2?

Comment: The Gabb Z2 is a locked down phone for a child's use. The manufacturer is free to put their own apps in their own Custom ROM and disable features. Based on [this XDA thread](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/installing-apps-on-a-gabb-phone-z2.4203577/page-13) a recent ROM update locked down `adb` access. Any public reveal of a workaround may result it being patched again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to downgrade the ROM to an older one with ADB access, disconnect it from Wi-Fi, and remove the SIM card. Then remove com.zte.zdm over ADB. After that, you can reconnect it and put the SIM card back.

To downgrade the ROM, disconnect the Wi-Fi and remove the SIM card, then turn it off. You then take it apart and remove the battery. You can downgrade the ROM using SP Flash Tool and a USB cable.

Comment: By this time, I'm afraid it's already too late because they can't enable ADB access due to [its Developer options being disabled](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/242600/44325).

Comment: @Andrew T. You disconnect the Wi-Fi and remove the SIM card, then turn it off You then take it apart and remove the battery. You can downgrade the ROM using SP Flash Tool and a USB cable.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot flash another ROM, this will brick your phone unless it is an older one.

There are no fixes for the newer phone right now.