# How to install APKs on Gabb Plus?

Tags: installation, apk, gabb

I would like to install an APK (specifically Google Maps and a few others) on my Gabb Phone Plus. It uses a modified version of Android, and Samsung made the phone itself. I downloaded the APK from [Aptoide](https://en.aptoide.com/) and scanned it with [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/upload). Then, I put it on an SD card and transferred it to my phone.

Once it was on my phone, I ran the APK. It didn't work. I tried it a few more times, and it said "Package installer keeps stopping." I tried to clear the cache, but couldn't. Then, I also force-quitted the app, and it didn't help at all.

I am thinking that Gabb did something to this to prevent APKs from being installed. I tried looking this up on Google, but apparently, not many people have the Plus because it only showed results for the Z2.

There must be a way to run APKs or put apps on the phone because I see Gabb installed their own apps on this phone.

Comment: If you search for ["gabb phone"  on this site](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=gabb+phone) you'll see a few questions about adding your own APK. As the manufacturer doesn't have the Google Play Store, none of the requirements (side loading, maps, etc.) are supported. With a custom ROM a manufacturer can block any non-authorized app. At a minimum the phone would need to be 'rooted' to know what could be done.

Comment: Search for Gabb hacking on the internet and you might find some private Discord servers. Feel free to join the server to follow the progress, because Gabb manufacturer is aggressive in locking their phones.

Comment: Fair point, I've reopened since this device might be different than other Gabb phones. However, still related: [How to install APK on Gabb Z2](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/241899/how-to-install-apk-on-gabb-z2?noredirect=1&lq=1) because AFAIK, all Gabb phones are locked deliberately by the vendor.

Comment: Im working on it now Im going through the files seeing if any of the Gabb apps or Knox E-FOTA has anything to do with it. Ill keep you updated to the best of my ability.

Comment: @CJJames Okay, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Gabb installed their own apps by changing the ROM image. This obviously cannot be done without some hardcore hardware hacks, but probably can be done. Since Gabb has officially reported that you may install apps from local apks, the 'Package Installer keeps stopping' seems to be a bug that probably resulted from something Gabb changed with the app. I have sent a report to Gabb through three different channels, I will notify if they send a solution that actually works or make a software update that works.

Comment: Where did you see that announcement?