# Gabb Phone Plus third party app installer

Tags: installation, apk, gabb

I am trying to download apps to my Gabb Plus and it once said (KPE INTERNAL ERROR) which might be different since I took out the SIM card and retried it. Is there a way to hook the phone up to a computer and use a third-party installer? Thanks!

THIS IS NOT A DUPE BECASE THIS IS DIFFRENT<3

Comment: Related/possible dupe: [How to install APKs on Gabb Plus?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/248188/44325). While this might not be an exact dupe, all app installation is processed directly on the phone by Package Installer, so it's no different whether the app is installed from the Play Store, from the PC through ADB, or from the APK file directly on the phone.

Comment: Andrew.T First of all its not a dupe,and second the phone is completely locked and they even changed the ROM image.More info here:https://gabbwireless.com/product/gabb-phone-plus/

Comment: Yes, Gabb phones are deliberately locked by the vendor so the the suggested duplicate (and comments) is applicable and the answer still is no, you can't, with or without SIM (the lock has nothing to do with the SIM), end of discussion.

Answer (score 2):

Your questions are answered on Gabb Wireless site for [Gabb Phone Plus phone](https://gabbwireless.com/product/gabb-phone-plus/).

Quoting from the FAQ at the bottom of the page:

> **Frequently Asked Questions**
>
> - **Can my child access apps or the internet on Gabb Plus Phone?**
>
>   Gabb Phone Plus does not have access to the internet or third party apps. **Only Gabb curated apps** like the calculator, contacts, Gabb Music (subscription required) and more can be used.
> - **Can the Gabb Phone Plus connect to WiFi?**
>
>   Yes, Wifi is available to help with phone features, but **only grants access to Gabb approved apps** for purposes such as streaming music through Gabb music (if you have a Gabb Music subscription) and software updates. Gabb Phone Plus does not have access to the internet, social media, or third party app store.
> - **Who manufacturers the Gabb Phone Plus?**
>
>   Samsung

Side note for:

`KPE_INTERNAL_ERROR` to me seem like Gabb Phone Plus is using [Samsung Knox Platform for Enterprise](https://docs.samsungknox.com/admin/knox-platform-for-enterprise/welcome.htm).

[Samsung Knox](https://www.samsungknox.com/en/solutions/it-solutions/knox-platform-for-enterprise) is a mobile device management service for use on Samsung phones in a business/government environment. Such devices can be locked down to prevent unauthorized use of many things including side-loading apps, camera/microphone usage, etc. Workers using such devices are probably using apps/data which is considered sensitive by their employer.

While nothing is unbreakable, given Samsung's interest in maintaining the aura of security and its client base, I have doubts that anyone on the open internet can/will tell you how to circumvent that security. Such things are much more valuable on the zero-day exploit/security vulnerability market.